# GWT 2.6 js null symbol, compiled mode

Tags: java, gwt, compiled

I get this error in FF/Chrome console when using the compiled version of my application saying:

```
"TypeError: a is null"
```

So I went to the symbol map and searched for symbol a but no occurrence ...
I don't get this error on hosted mode, and it only started to appear since migrating to GWT 2.6
Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, if anybody's facing the same problem when on **compiled** mode, look for the **symbolMap** of the correct permutation in your **WEB-INF/deploy** folder.
This helped me to find which method is causing the error and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to compile in Pretty mode to have a more explicit symbol name.

Not sure it has anything to do with GWT 2.6. Same code in GWT 2.5.1 does not have the same error ?

Comment: no it didn't show this error in 2.5, it's a non blocking error since everything works fine. I translated the stack trace using the symbolMap file, so I'm trying to figure out the problem ...